# Remove the list items in column more than one combination in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here][1]

I have obtained a DataFrame of compounds given below, whereas BaSiO3 has two possibilities. Now I want to remove one of them.

```
 (ABO3)         (A_OS,   B_OS)

 ['CaFeO3']       [3, 2]

 ['BaSiO3']       [1,5], [4, 2]

 ['BaGeO3']       [4, 2]
```

Desired output is :

```
 (ABO3)         (A_OS,   B_OS)

 ['CaFeO3']       [3,2]

 ['BaSiO3']       [1,5] 

 ['BaGeO3']       [4,2]
```

I have tried to create this dataframe as follows:

```
res = ['CeTmO3', 'CeLuO3', 'CeRhO3']
list1 = [['Ce', 'Tm', 'O'],  ['Ce', 'Lu', 'O'],  ['Ce', 'Rh', 'O']]   # to extract the properties of elements

A = []
B = []
final = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
   A = element(list1[i][0]).oxistates   # Only calling the Oxidation- 
   B = element(list1[i][1]).oxistates   # states of A and B
   D = A,B
   final.append(D)
#print(final)

solutions = []
for x in range(len(final)):  #for y in range((len(final[x]))):
   E = [(x1,x2) for x1 in final[x][0] for x2 in final[x][1] if sum([x1,x2]) == 6]
   solutions.append(E)
#print(solutions)

list2 = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(res, solutions)] 
list2
```

and then

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataPd1 = pd.DataFrame(res)
data = np.array(solutions)
dataPd2 = pd.DataFrame(data = data)

df_os = pd.concat([dataPd1,dataPd2],axis=1)
df_os.columns = ["ABO3", "Oxi_State"]
df_os
```

Now in the above code, 'CeTmO3' and 'CeRhO3' have two possibilities. I want only one and delete other. Like as:

```
    ABO3    Oxi_State
0   CeTmO3  [(4, 2), (3, 3)]
1   CeLuO3  [(3, 3)]
2   CeRhO3  [(4, 2), (3, 3)]
```

The desired one is:

```
    ABO3    Oxi_State
0   CeTmO3  [(4, 2)]
1   CeLuO3  [(3, 3)]
2   CeRhO3  [(4, 2)]
```

Please note that few compounds have more than two possibilities also in the original data set. For ex:

```
 BrNO3  [(7,-1),(5,1),(3,3),(1,5)]
```

Comment: please provide code to reproduce the DataFrame as a valid object

Comment: the code is very very lengthy, that is why a part of problem is mentioned. As number of items are 27894 and  I had given only 3.

Comment: Also, how are you getting the data for the original dataframe?  Is it being pulled from a spreadsheet, an csv formatted file, web site etc.?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: Well, we do not need 17894 rows, just provide 3: `df.head(3).to_dict('list')`

Comment: I have just updated the code there, please see @itprorh66. Hoping, it is now more understandable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach, assuming the desired compound is always the first one listed, given a df of the form:

```
    ABO3    Oxi_State
0   CeTmO3  [(4, 2), (3, 3)]
1   CeLuO3  [(3, 3)]
2   CeRhO3  [(4, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Is to utilize the following approach:

```
df['Oxi_State'] = [[x[0]] for x in df['Oxi_State'].to_list()]
```

This produces:

```
    ABO3    Oxi_State
0   CeTmO3  [(4, 2)]
1   CeLuO3  [(3, 3)]
2   CeRhO3  [(4, 2)]
```

​